# Generating event handler in VS2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, event-handling

I am trying to generate an event handler in windows form application. When I write

```
myAlgorithm.nextNodeFound +=
```

and press 'Tab' two times it generates a new handler automatically but this handler works on EventArgs, what I need is to have a handler that works with `CustomEventArgs`. I tried to modify the signature of auto generated handler but then it gives the error

> *No overload for myAlgo_nextNodeFound matches delegate
>   System.EventHandler*

Please suggest how to make it work.

Comment: How have you declared `myAlgorithm.nextNodeFound`?

Comment: Class MyAlgo { public event EventHandler nextNodeFound;}

Comment: @user2324189: Well exactly look at the declaration of `EventHandler`. It doesn't take a `CustomEventArgs`, just an `EventArgs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you've declared your `nextNodeFound` event to be of type `EventHandler`. If you need it to work with your custom args, you should use a delegate type which uses the right parameters... the generic [`EventHandler<TEventArgs>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx) type is probably what you want:

```
public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> NextNodeFound;
```

Note that I've changed the name of the comply with .NET naming conventions. This is also assuming that `CustomEventArgs` derives from `EventArgs` - if it doesn't already, I suggest you make it do so. You might also want to change the name to indicate *how* it's custom - such as `NodeTraversalEventArgs` or something similar.

It sounds like you may be relatively new to .NET events - you might want to read my [article on events and delegates](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx).

Comment: Blimey, you can type fast! I was just waiting for him to answer my comment ;-)

Comment: I am not getting what you are pointing at my code is like this
  <code>  class MyAlgo
    {
        public event EventHandler nextNodeFound;

        public void RunAlgo()
        {
            CustomEventArgs args = new CustomEventArgs();
            args.Direction = "Up";
            args.Distance = 5;
            this.nextNodeFound(this, args);
        }
    }
    class CustomEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Direction { get; set; }
        public float Distance { get; set; }
    }<code>

Comment: @user2324189: I'm saying that you've declared `nextNodeFound` as being of type `EventHandler`, but you should have declared it to be of type `EventHandler<CustomEventArgs>` because the event has more information.

Comment: Yes, I am new to .Net events. 

Ok I got it what you are saying, but the problem is that the example I am looking at right now, is doing exactly what I am trying to do, but I am unable to replicate it.

Comment: @user2324189: I don't understand the problem. I've told you twice *exactly* how to fix the problem. What happened when you tried to fix it as I've suggested? Either the example you're looking at *doesn't* do what you need to do, or it's incorrect, or the event handler methods would need to cast `EventArgs` to `CustomEventArgs` (which is a really bad idea).

Comment: Ok I got it now. Used your suggestion and it worked and then realized that I was just overlooking the <CustomEventArgs> part in the example also. Sorry, my mistake, I think should go to bed now, its 2am. Thanks for your help.